# SonarQube quality gate status fetching issue

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to get the status of SonarQube quality gate status using below query

curl.exe -u "78c2b8628934a6cdc8ae80f5acadaaaafdfsa96" : "https://sonarurl/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=MarUiSonarQube3"

then system prompted for password, after that I got below error:

Did I miss something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>IIS Windows</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
        color:#000000;
        background-color:#0072C6;
        margin:0;
}

#container {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        text-align:center;
        }

a img {
        border:none;
}

-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=66138&amp;clcid=0x409"><img src="iisstart.png" alt="IIS" width="960" height="600" /></a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you specified is the following:

```
curl.exe -u "78c2b8628934a6cdc8ae80f5acadaaaafdfsa96" : "https://sonarurl/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=MarUiSonarQube3"
```

The way you've specified the token value looks slightly off.  Try changing it to the following (moving the colon to right after the token):

```
curl.exe -u "78c2b8628934a6cdc8ae80f5acadaaaafdfsa96:" "https://sonarurl/api/qualitygates/project_status?projectKey=MarUiSonarQube3"
```